# How to print a system of linear equations in matrix form using sweave?

Tags: r, sweave

I would like to print a system of linear equations, a right bracket, a right arrow and finally the output of the system (x). Something like Ax = b } ---> x. It is hard for me to find the right way of working with many matrices/vectors one behind the others. My code is:

```
    a = c(-scan(text="89 82 14"),scan(text="98 17 55"),scan(text="59 88 89"))
    A = matrix(a,nrow=3,byrow=T)
    b = c(-50,53,82)
    x=solve(A)%*%b
```

The format would be something like:

```
\left Ax=b \} \right \Longrightarrow x=(..)
```

Then I would like to change b to be d=b+\Delta b_i and solve again the system so I get the format:

```
dia=diag(1,3,3)
x=[solve(A)%*%b]+\Delta b_1[solve(A)%*%dia[,1]]+\Delta b_3[solve(A)%*%dia[,2]]+\Delta b_3[solve(A)%*%dia[,3]].
```

I have plotted individual matrices using `xtable` but never have concatenated a few at the same time.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (using AMS stuff):

```
\left. \begin{pmatrix} ... \end{pmatrix} \right\} \longrightarrow x
```

should do. Or am I completely off-track here?

Comment: thanks for your answer. My idea is that the matrices created in the chunk are automatically allocated in the document without having to type each element, row, etc. What is the easiest way of doing it?